# How do i use with statement in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I have a main function that uses every other function using this code:

```elixir
File.read!(file_path)
|> Sanitizer.sanitize_source()
|> IO.inspect(label: "\nSanitizer ouput")
|> Lexer.scan_words()
|> IO.inspect(label: "\nLexer ouput")
|> Parser.parse_program()
|> IO.inspect(label: "\nParser ouput")
|> CodeGenerator.generate_code()
|> Linker.generate_binary(assembly_path
```

But anytime a function returns an error, the rest causes the program to crash. My teacher told me to use `with` instead to solve this and after reading the documentation i came up with this:

```elixir
with {:ok, contentF} <- File.read!(file_path)
         sanitizedList when is_list(sanitizedList) <- Sanitizer.sanitize_source(contentF)
         {:ok, _sMessage} <- IO.inspect(sanitizedList, label: "\nSanitizer output")
         lexedList when not is_tuple(errorLex) <- Lexer.scan_words(sanitizedList)
         {:ok, _sMessage} <- IO.inspect(lexedList, label: "\nLexer output")
         parsedAST when not is_tuple(errorPar) <- Parser.parse_program(lexedList)
         {:ok, _sMessage} <- IO.inspect(parsedAST, label: "\nParser output")
         {:ok, codeAssembly} <- CodeGenerator.generate_code(parsedAST)
         :ok <- Linker.generate_binary(codeAssembly, assembly_path)
    do
      {:ok, "compilation complete"}
    else
      error -> {:error, "error: couldn't compile the file" <> file_path}
    end
```

From what i've read, this should at least compile, but it gives me the error

```elixir
(CompileError) lib/nqcc.ex:32: missing :do option in "with"
    lib/nqcc.ex:28: (module)
```

I'm not really sure why, i do have a `do` statement.

If it helps, this is what every function should return:

`Sanitizer.sanitize_source()` should return a list of tuples

`Lexer.scan_words()` should return a list of tuples or `{:error, "message"}`

`Parser.parse_program()` should return an AST or `{:error, "message"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should check out the documentation for [`with/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#with/1).

In Elixir, it's common for functions to have to variants, one that ends in an exclamation mark like [`File.read!/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/File.html#read!/1) that raises an error, and one without the exclamation mark like [`File.read/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/File.html#read/1) that returns an `{:ok, result}` tuple on success or an `{:error, error}` tuple on failure.

To use `with` effectively, it's helpful to use the versions without an exclamation mark that return an error tuple instead of raising an error. Once you have that, you can match on the successful `{:ok, result}` tuples. If there is an error, it will return the `{:error, error}` tuple.

I can't test your code without the full implementation of the fuctions, but it should probably look something like this (don't forget the commas at the end of the lines!):

```elixir
with {:ok, contentF} <- File.read(file_path),
     {:ok, sMessage} <- Sanitizer.sanitize_source(contentF),
     {:ok, lexedList} <- Lexer.scan_words(sanitizedList),
     {:ok, parsedAST} <- Parser.parse_program(lexedList),
     {:ok, codeAssembly} <- CodeGenerator.generate_code(parsedAST),
     :ok <- Linker.generate_binary(codeAssembly, assembly_path) do
  {:ok, "compilation complete"}
end
```

If you want to put in `IO.inspect` calls for debugging:

```elixir
with {:ok, contentF} <- File.read(file_path),
     {:ok, sMessage} <- Sanitizer.sanitize_source(contentF),
     IO.inspect(sMessage, label: "\nSanitizer ouput"),
     {:ok, lexedList} <- Lexer.scan_words(sanitizedList),
     IO.inspect(lexedList, label: "\nLexer ouput"),
     {:ok, parsedAST} <- Parser.parse_program(lexedList),
     IO.inspect(parsedAST, label: "\nParser ouput"),
     {:ok, codeAssembly} <- CodeGenerator.generate_code(parsedAST),
     :ok <- Linker.generate_binary(codeAssembly, assembly_path) do
  {:ok, "compilation complete"}
end
```

Edit: If you can't edit the original functions and want to match it using guards, it should like something like this (again, it's difficult to tell without being able to test it):

```elixir
with {:ok, contentF} <- File.read(file_path),
     sanitizedList when is_list(sanitizedList) <- Sanitizer.sanitize_source(contentF),
     IO.inspect(sanitizedList, label: "\nSanitizer output"),
     lexedList when not is_tuple(errorLex) <- Lexer.scan_words(sanitizedList),
     IO.inspect(lexedList, label: "\nLexer output"),
     parsedAST when not is_tuple(errorPar) <- Parser.parse_program(lexedList),
     IO.inspect(parsedAST, label: "\nParser output"),
     {:ok, codeAssembly} <- CodeGenerator.generate_code(parsedAST),
     :ok <- Linker.generate_binary(codeAssembly, assembly_path) do
  {:ok, "compilation complete"}
end
```

Comment: Sadly it didn't work. I get the warning ````The pattern {'ok', _sanitizedList@1} can never match the type [binary()]````. If i ignore that, i get a similar warning for lexer, parser and codeGenerator.

Comment: That's because you need to write versions of `Sanitizer.sanitize_source` etc. that return `{:ok, result}` tuples.

Comment: Isn't it possible to match that using guards?

Comment: Should be. What happens if you add commas to the end of the lines in your original version?

Comment: @GiezyRamírez I added a reformatted example of your version with guards.

Comment: @GiezyRamírez “I get the warning The pattern [...]” — you should clearly understand the difference between _dialyzer_ (static code analysis tool, that does not affect compilation by any means) and the compilation process itself. The warning comes from dialyzer and you’d better start with the plain compilation, error messages would be more concise. Later on, when everything would work, you might resort to check the code with dialyzer.

Comment: I managed to make it work using guards but now i ran into a bigger problem. I need the IO.inspect to work even if the match fails. The IO.inspect is supposed to print the result if the function works and the error message if it fails. Tried doing it on the functions but it's practically impossible.

Comment: You can put an inspect inside the else clause: `else error -> IO.inspect(error)`. Or you could wrap the whole `with` expression in an IO.inspect call. IO.inspect always returns the value of its argument - the logging is a side-effect that should not affect your pipeline.

Comment: @GiezyRamírez if the answer helped, you are supposed to mark it as correct and (optionally) upvote it before asking further unrelated questions having nothing to do with the original one. If you have doubt about anything else, feel free to post another question. The goal of SO is not to help you, but to create a knowledge base, that’s why you must follow rules: mark correct questions as correct _and_ do not ask a bunch of unrelated questions at once.

Answer (score 0):

*TL;DR:* the error is induced by the lack of commas between `with/1` clauses. Also, `File.read!/1` returns a content, or raises; to pattern match to {:ok, _} tuple you should use `File.read/1` (without bang.) With these two corrections, the code should work.

---

> `foo` should return *`result`* or *`{:ok, error}`* tuple.

This is a design flaw, preventing you from using `with/1` in an idiomatic, readable way. Whether the function has a monadic behavior, one should resort to returning `{:ok, result}` and `{:error, reason}` tuples. Check `File.read/1` for inspiration.

So, whether `Sanitizer`, `Lexer`, and `Parser` are yours, update the respective functions to return tuples in both cases. If not, provide a helper as shown below

```rb
defp idiomatize({:error, reason}), do: {:error, reason}
defp idiomatize(result), do: {:ok, result}
```

While you obviously can achieve this result with guards, the code quickly becomes unreadable and unsupportable. With the helper above you might do

```rb
with {:ok, contentF} <- File.read(file_path),
     {:ok, sanitizedList} <- idiomatize(Sanitizer.sanitize_source(contentF)),
     IO.inspect(sanitizedList, label: "\nSanitizer output"),
     {:ok, lexedList} <- idiomatize(Lexer.scan_words(sanitizedList)),
     IO.inspect(lexedList, label: "\nLexer output"),
     {:ok, parsedAST} <- idiomatize(Parser.parse_program(lexedList)),
     IO.inspect(parsedAST, label: "\nParser output"),
     {:ok, codeAssembly} <- CodeGenerator.generate_code(parsedAST),
     :ok <- Linker.generate_binary(codeAssembly, assembly_path)
    do
      {:ok, "compilation complete"}
    else
      {:error, error} ->
        {:error, "error: couldn't compile the file" <> file_path}
end
```